# Java class TrayIcon, notification message. How to replace system sound with a custom one?

Tags: java, windows, swing, audio, desktop

Java class TrayIcon, notification message. How to replace system sound with a custom one?
Perhaps I need to mute system sound and play mine? Any exec command to do that?

**UPDATE: essential part of working notification on  windows's tray**

```
public void notifyIt() {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        try {
            mPromptClock.displayTray();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("System tray not supported!");
    }
}

private void displayTray() throws AWTException {
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    File f = new File("./src/res/0.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Vaqt  bo'ldi");
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    trayIcon.setToolTip("1st message");
    tray.add(trayIcon);
    trayIcon.displayMessage("2nd message"+navbat, "Vaqtingiz bo'ldi", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);//Navbat
}
```

Comment: Hey, where are those super-puper java devs :( . I cannot replace TrayIcon in my app  as it doesnt interfere  while typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using TrayIcon.

The native implementation for TrayIcon displayMessage [calls](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/05a764f4ffb8030d6b768f2d362c388e5aabd92d/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_TrayIcon.cpp) [Shell_NotifyIconW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw) to display a notification. The [NOTIFYICONDATAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw) data you pass to this function does not provide a way to use a custom audio file, but you can set a dwInfoFlags (NIIF_NOSOUND) to disable the sound that plays. TrayIcon does not expose a way to set this set.

You will have to call this function yourself and play your own sound yourself if you want the same notification behavior.